# Restrict Images on Rich Text Editor in oracle apex 18.2

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Rich text editor of CLOB data type in apex 18.2, can I restrict users from pasting images in the field.

Can I show some error message when they are trying to paste images.

Please suggest.

Regards,

SwaZ

Answer (score 0):

APEX uses CKEditor for the rich text editor. APEX 19.2 uses CKEditor v4.11.4. You can find the documentation here:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/

There's a configuration setting named pasteFilter:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-pasteFilter

Configuration options can be set using the **JavaScript Initialization** option (in the Advanced section) of the item. I added the following code to that setting and it prevented images from being pasted in:

```
function (options) {
  options.pasteFilter = 'img';

  return options;
}
```

`pasteFromWord_inlineImages` may be useful as well.

You can also play with the `allowedContent` and `disallowedContent` settings, which apply to more than just pasting.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything simple that allowed for the specification of a function that could do more interesting things on paste. I suspect if you need additional functionality, such at prompting the user about the removal of the image or differentiating images that have base64 encoded images vs URLs, things would get complicated quickly.